# SEO - Meta Description Tags Not Updating Search Result

Tags: seo, search, meta-tags

I updated my meta description tag for my comics website about two months back now, but the search engine is still picking up my footer "Acceptable User Policy" text for some reason.

[image]

[image]

I'm not even sure why it would pick up this footer text to begin with:

[image]

I need this to be updated because I don't want my search result to be about my disclaimer... I want it to be about the content of my site- comics.

How long should it take to update? Do I have the tag incorrect?

**EDIT----- Meta Description Tag length:**

```
"Hitting Trees with Sticks is dedicated to sharing high quality original satirical comics with the world."

Words: 16
Characters (no spaces): 89
Characters (with spaces): 104
```

Thanks!

Comment: How long is the content of the tag?

Comment: @Kenzo see above edit

Comment: That's fine then. Looks like you need a recrawl and Google update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not necessarily use the `meta` description in the SERPs. It uses whatever text it *thinks* is appropriate, which may or may not include (part of) the meta description.

(Google updated its cache of your homepage less than two weeks ago on 28 Dec 2012.)

---

**EDIT (2013-01-15):** Interesting to note that I see today your updated title and description are now showing in Google SERPs. However, Google's cache of your page is still the one from 28 Dec 2012 with the old title and description. So it would seem that what's shown in the SERPs and Google's cache are not necessarily related (or in sync)!?

Comment: Oh, then that may be what's happening because I've had that meta description up for a while. I certainly don't want it to show my footer copyright info as my search result. How can I fix this?

Comment: Rather curious... you say you updated the `description` (and `title` I assume) two months ago and Google's cached copy of your page is from 28 Dec 2012 (2 weeks ago) - yet it appears to have an old title and description?! This could explain why Google is showing your footer text... it is the only part of the page content that contains your search phrase "hitting trees with sticks".

Answer (score 2):

It is almost certainly down to Google not re indexing your site. A good way to check this is to view Google's cached version of your site (click the double arrow that appears next to your search result when you hover over your link, then click 'cached')

Whilst you're looking at the cached page you can see whether the update meta tags are there, if not, your site hasn't been re-indexed.

A way to speed the process up is to submit your URL to the index tool in Webmaster Tools although this has no guarantee to work!

Comment: in GWT you may re-index the site, which MAY speed up the re-indexing of said page.

Answer (score 1):

How fast your site is automatically recrawled depends, among other things, on your Google karma.  Which - based upon your public PR - is not too hot at the moment.

However, in GWT there is a "Submit URL to Index"-tool.  If you use it Google will usually recrawl the URL submitted within 48 hours (but there are no guarantees, and Google may start to ignore you if you abuse it).

However, I think your main problem vis a vis Google is total lack of content.  Your site consists almost entirely of images, which - just by themselves - Google don't consider "content" (hence Google using the AUP, which is about the only text of substance to be found). Since you haven't placed any meaningful "title" and "alt" tags on your site, Google thinks it is with no content, and worse, Google thinks your meta-tag description of your site is just black-hat SEO trickery and refuses to display it.

Take a look of the source code of the http://xkcd.com/ to see how they tag their images to make Google index their site.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tools. Just curious, how are you figuring that my PR is not too hot at the moment?

Comment: Several options exists, such as the Google Toolbar, and http://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php

Comment: lol omg, I got a score of 0/10... How do I improve that? GoDaddy gave me a SEO score of 60%, I'm not sure how my PR is is zero... Oh man soo much to learn!

Comment: I can't help you with the PR.  Most of my sites has PR of 4-5/10, with one at 6/10, but I've never paid much attention to SEO beyond obvious stuff such as making sure my headings are representative for contents, etc.  I think good content is the key to a nice PR, and that people who spend time and money on SEO rather than contents has their priorities wrong.

Comment: However, your site consists mostly of images, which Google don't consider interesting content (hence Google using the AUP, which is about the only text of substance to be found).  Since there are no meaningful "title" and "alt" tags on your site, Google thinks it is with no content.

Comment: And since I'm at it.  You use a CC BY NC SA license. This means that *anyone* is licensed to create derivatives of your artwork, where they can edit out *anything* they want, including logos and trademarks. In the AUP you state: "You may not remove Hitting Trees with Sticks (HTwS) logos or trademarks from any work originating from this website".  This is contradictory, and if you're ever in a legal dispute about this, I pretty sure the CC BY NC SA will prevail.

Comment: Wow, good to know. I thought SA (Share Alike) meant that they can share it as long as it's alike to my original and that the Attribution specified that they need to attribute it back to me. Which CC license should I use then if I want it to be like my AUP?

Comment: Share alike means can share as long as any derivatives (=changed versions of your artwork) use the *same* CC license.  You should use CC BY NC ND.

Answer (score 0):

Google will choose the description to display based on the ctr of the url. The meta you put into your site is a suggestion for Google. They can create a different title and summary in serps. That's why many people believe no meta description will give them more information into how google sees their site.